# Example of using Coffeescript classes and RequireJS (or Curljs or similar) for client side browser library

Tags: coffeescript, requirejs, curljs

We want to develop a browser (client side only) library using Coffeescript, and in particular, we tend to use the "class" capability of Coffeescript quite a bit, in addition to pure functions. The library will be relatively large, so we want to start out using a well defined module pattern, but not to the point where we want a single coffee file for every coffeescript "class". We don't want to compile the coffee files on the fly, but rather as a specific build step, and would prefer to not have to concat all the outputted JS into one file. As a final requirement, we will be using something like Jasmine for testing.

Does anyone know of a good example library developed in this way, using Coffeescript with something such as RequireJS, CurlJS, Browserify etc? I have looked on Github, and there are some examples, but I couldn't see anything specific to my needs.

I tried [Coffee-Toaster](http://github.com/serpentem/coffee-toaster) , as it seemed to hold some promise in making it simple to define dependencies etc, but it failed to deal with Windows paths (the old \ vs /), so gave up on that, mainly because it seemed to be a bit on the "light" side - something like RequireJS would seem to have a much better community support behind it.

Thanks for any help you can provide. I am really looking for working source code examples if possible.

Comment: I tweeted this question. Let's see if somebody responds.

Comment: Does attaching shared objects to `window` and just compiling each file separately not work?  The CoffeeScript compiler doesn't do any checking that would require files to be compiled in a specific order, or be able to access one another at compile-time.

Comment: CoffeeToaster author's note: I'm implementing AMD standards in Toaster. It'd change a lot of what it is now, but in the end I believe it'd be very useful and simple to use. Plus users can use any AMD loader they want, but Toaster will probably have it's own micro implementation.

Comment: Btw, the windows support was implemented in CoffeeToaster. Update to the latest version and everything should work.

Answer (score 37):

First off, if you're using RequireJS you're going to have a not-easy time returning multiple "things" from a define function. RequireJS uses AMD (!NOT! CommonJS) format "standards", which doesn't contain a module.exports object for exporting "stuff" but instead relies on return something.

With that said, I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for here but having a class work with RequireJS is pretty easy. Something like this:

```
define ['my/required/module'], (myModule) ->
    class MyOtherModule
        privateField = 0

        constructor: ->
        publicMethod: ->

    return MyOtherModule
```

This can be used in a require/define function just like any other script. Take this example:

```
require ['my/other/module'], (MyOtherModule) ->
    instance = new MyOtherModule()
```

We can even use it with "extends"

```
define ['my/other/module'], (MyOtherModule) ->
    class MyThirdModule extends MyOtherModule
        ...
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: `return MyOtherModule` is redundant. Simply by saying `class MyOtherModule`, you are retruning it if it's the last thing in the scope (e.g., there is nothing else after the class _block_).

Comment: Agreed return is totally redundant given how CoffeeScript will return the last executed expression automagically. However, I still leave put it there in most cases as I feel it makes the code more readable for those who are new to/still learning CoffeeScript (most of my team).

Comment: Awfully nice of you. I work alone so it never occurred to me. :)

Comment: +1 to the explicit return. Readability matters so much more than saving 2 seconds of typing! The auto return feature is, IMHO, a return to the Perl aesthetic of "save typing at all costs. ALL COSTS I MEAN!" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using coffee-toaster too, and I found few posts recently.
I thought that was worth to read, maybe we could work it out:

http://blog.toastymofo.net/2012/04/coffeescript-requirejs-and-you-part-one.html
http://24ways.org/2012/think-first-code-later/

and http://jamjs.org seems pretty cool!

Comment: Coffee-Toaster author's note: I'm planning to add transparent AMD support in CoffeeToaster in order to achieve modular & parallel loading

Comment: for any one who is coming though this ... Coffee-Toaster development is now discontinued as of April 12, 2013

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually used this technique yet, but:

The only thing to keep in mind here is that CoffeeScript statements are also return values when they are last in a function. So, basically, the following code:

```
define [], () ->
  class Main
```

translates to:

```
define([], function() {
  var Main;
  return Main = (function() {

    function Main() {}

    return Main;

  })();
});
```

and that should work as expected (I see no reason why it wouldn't based on the compiled JavaScript).

For managing code base, I believe the [CS plugin](https://github.com/jrburke/require-cs) should come in handy. It's maintained by James Burke himself, and supports building of CoffeeScript projects the same way JavaScript projects are built.