# Knockout.js loop through divs on page and generate button. coffeescript

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, coffeescript

I am trying to loop through all the divs on the page and find all the ones with the same class same: item and turn them into  a button.

Here is an example of the data in the html:

```
         <div class='item'>
          <span><a class='test' href='http://google.com'>tester1</a></span>
          </div>
          <div class='item'>
          <span><a class='test' href='http://google.com'>tester2</a></span>
          </div>
          <div class='item'>
          <span><a class='test' href='http://google.com'>tester</a></span>
          </div>
          <div class='item'>
          <span><a class='test' href='http://google.com'>test</a></span>
          </div>
```

The issue is hundreds of these divs might exist so that is why I want to use ko.

my coffeescript:

```
define ["knockout", "text!./test-page.html"], (ko, template) ->
VM = () =>
    window.xxx = @


return {
    viewModel: VM
    template: template
}
```

I am unsure how to proceed, any tips to put me in the right direction?

Comment: Aren't you using `RequireJS`? The question should be tagged that too. Never used Coffeescript, but when I compare your Cs with regular JS [here](http://js2coffee.org/) you should start by fixing the indentation, which seems crucial for Cs, then read [Knockout and AMD modules](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/amd-loading.html#loading-knockoutjs-a-binding-handler-and-a-viewmodel-class-via-requirejs), and [this Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389803/example-of-using-coffeescript-classes-and-requirejs-or-curljs-or-similar-for-c) & probably also learn OO JS concepts.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use a jQuery selector and then for each element returned convert it to a button? e.g. `$(".item").each(function(){...turn to button...})`

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Is it hard coded?

Comment: If you want to use knockout for this you would most likely not search through the DOM to find divs. If you want to use knockout for this you would probably let knockout create the divs in the first place and have a bindingHandler which makes it into a button (however, why not just make it an actual HTML button too, while you are at it?). The way you are asking about (searching through the DOM) is more of a jQuery way, not knockout way, of doing things. For jQuery, look at @Jarga's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you have enough there to use Knockout to do this. Perhaps put a fiddle together?

You could achieve this using jQuery however and then let Knockout know things have changed if need be.

```
$('.item').each ->
 if $(this).hasClass 'buttonClass'
  // turn $(this) into a button and manipulate in other ways
 else
 // ad a class or something that lets you find these in the future perhaps?
```